# "/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: *: not found" error when removing kernel packages

Tags: grub2, apt, dpkg

I need to install some stuff but it says I need to remove Linux Kernel Image for version 3.11.0-12-generic and Linux Kernel extra for version 3.11.0-12-generic. Please help.

```
miles@Ubuntu-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for miles: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 183 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 185492 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

/etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash profile”
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Welcome to AU! This looks like an unconfigured package issue. Can you run `sudo apt-get install -f` and append or attach the output to your question?

Comment: Okay I did that is says I need to remove 2 things and it gave me an error what do I do know and thank you so much for helping

Comment: The Error is 

Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the configuration file `/etc/default/grub`. Can you append that to your question as well (if it's short enough), or upload it to a [paste service](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and link it here?

Comment: Perhaps try `sudo apt-get autoremove` first.

Comment: @douggro: No, that won't work either under the circumstances because the post-removal script will fail either way.

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6613194/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install anything because there are broken packages on your system. Considering the output of `apt-get install -f`, their removal fails because of an error in [your `/etc/default/grub`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6613194/), line 11:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash profile”
```

Those aren't the quotation marks you're looking for. You need a pair of either `"` or `'` instead. You can change them manually or with

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/”/"/g' /etc/default/grub
```

Afterwards you can retry to remove those broken packages (`sudo apt-get install -f`).

Comment: Thank you I needed to install some stuff for touch screen thank you so much

Comment: If this answer resolved the issue, please consider [accepting it](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).